# Finding Dominant Strategy, Pure Nash Equilibrium and Mixed Nash Equilibrium in 2 player zero-sum game

Tags: python, algorithm, economics, game-theory

I am solving Computational Game Theory problems. I want to check if any two player zero-sum game has Dominant Strategy, Pure Nash Equilibrium and Mixed Nash Equilibrium.

I know that unfortunately Dominant Strategy and Pure Nash Equilibrium does not always exists. As far i know finding Mixed Nash Equilibrium is considerably harder than finding Dominant Strategy solutions or Pure Nash Equilibrium, even when the game is finite and there are only a constant number of players. But couldn't figure it out why?

I want to know how can I find them or can check if there exists any DS, PNE and MNE, for any two player zero-sum game. For example consider a zero-sum game given by the following matrix:

[image]I would really appreciate it if someone can give me a better explanation about how to check if the above game has any Dominant Strategy, Pure Nash Equilibrium and Mixed Nash Equilibrium.

**N.B. The example above is used just to make my question more clearer. You are welcome to explain this approach with any other matrix. Any resource link that has a clear derivation will also be count as an answer to my question.**

Comment: Since it looks like homework, I’ll just say: That game doesn’t have a pure strategy NE; no dominant strategy eq. either. It has a mixed strategy eq. however. If you’re using a computer to solve, it’s probably easiest to model it as a linear programming problem and solve it. But it’s also easy to solve by hand too. There are countless online tutorials that will help you.

Comment: @enke I appreciate your response, but its just a random example. The values doesn't matter for me. Anyone can explain the approach with any example that they like. I am looking for the derivation of the approach. Like you have said there is no NE and DS for the above game, but I would like to know how the method to be sure about for any such games. If you can share a direct link of any site that shows the proper derivation of tow player zero-sum game that would be really helpful too. But all I have found so far are either more than two player or just the theory.

Answer (score 0):

The below functions provide a simple implementation for checking dominating strategy and pure Nash equilibrium for a 2-player game.

To find a dominant strategy for a given player we need to check if there exists a strategy that always leads to better payoff, irrespective of the other player's strategy.

To check whether a given pair of moves corresponds to a (pure) Nash equilibrium, we need to check whether any of the players can do better by changing his strategy or not.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_dominating_strategy(player, payoffs_df, other_strategies):
    other_player = 'p2' if player == 'p1' else 'p1'
    all_best_strategies = set([])
    for other_strategy in other_strategies:
        sdf = payoffs_df[payoffs_df[other_player + '_strategy'] == other_strategy]
        cur_strategy = sdf.loc[sdf[player + '_payoff'].idxmax(), player + '_strategy']
        all_best_strategies.add(cur_strategy)
    return list(all_best_strategies)[0] if len(all_best_strategies) == 1 else None

def exists_better_strategy(player, cur_strategy, cur_payoff, other_strategy, payoffs_df, strategies):
    other_player = 'p2' if player == 'p1' else 'p1'
    sdf = payoffs_df[payoffs_df[other_player + '_strategy'] == other_strategy]
    for i in sdf.index:
        if sdf.loc[i, player + '_payoff'] > cur_payoff:
            return True
    return False
            
def get_pure_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies):
    nash_equlibriums = []
    for i in range(len(payoffs_df)):
        cur_state = payoffs_df.loc[i]
        p1_payoff, p2_payoff = cur_state['p1_payoff'], cur_state['p2_payoff']
        p1_strategy, p2_strategy = cur_state['p1_strategy'], cur_state['p2_strategy']
        nash_equlibrium_found = True
        if exists_better_strategy('p1', p1_strategy, p1_payoff, p2_strategy, payoffs_df, p1_strategies):
            nash_equlibrium_found = False
            continue
        if exists_better_strategy('p2', p2_strategy, p2_payoff, p1_strategy, payoffs_df, p2_strategies):
            nash_equlibrium_found = False
            continue
        if nash_equlibrium_found:
            nash_equlibriums.append((p1_strategy, p2_strategy))
    return None if len(nash_equlibriums) == 0 else nash_equlibriums
```

Now, let's test for the famous Prisoner Dilemma game with the following payoff table, here let's use `pandas` `DataFrame` to store the utility table.

[image]

```
p1_strategies = ['confess', 'silent']
p2_strategies = ['confess', 'silent']
payoffs_PD = pd.DataFrame({'p1_strategy': ['confess', 'confess', 'silent', 'silent'],
                           'p2_strategy': ['confess', 'silent', 'confess', 'silent'],
                           'p1_payoff': [0, 3, -1, 1],
                           'p2_payoff': [0, -1, 3, 1]})

print(payoffs_PD)  # utilities
#       p1_strategy p2_strategy  p1_payoff  p2_payoff
# 0     confess     confess          0          0
# 1     confess      silent          3         -1
# 2      silent     confess         -1          3
# 3      silent      silent          1          1

ds_p1 = get_dominating_strategy('p1', payoffs_PD, p2_strategies)
ds_p2 = get_dominating_strategy('p2', payoffs_PD, p1_strategies)
print(ds_p1, ds_p2) # dominating strategy for the players
# confess confess

nes = get_pure_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_PD, p1_strategies, p2_strategies)
# pure Nash equlibriums, only 1 here
print(nes)
# [('confess', 'confess')]
```

Let's test with another game with the following utilities:

```
p1_strategies = ['T', 'B']
p2_strategies = ['L', 'R']
payoffs_df = pd.DataFrame({'p1_strategy': ['T', 'T', 'B', 'B'],
                           'p2_strategy': ['L', 'R', 'L', 'R'],
                           'p1_payoff': [7, 0, 2, 4],
                           'p2_payoff': [6, 5, 0, 3]})

print(payoffs_df)
#   p1_strategy p2_strategy  p1_payoff  p2_payoff
# 0           T           L          7          6
# 1           T           R          0          5
# 2           B           L          2          0
# 3           B           R          4          3

ds_p1 = get_dominating_strategy('p1', payoffs_df, p2_strategies)
ds_p2 = get_dominating_strategy('p2', payoffs_df, p1_strategies)
print(ds_p1, ds_p2) # no dominating strategy exists for any of the players
# None None

nes = get_pure_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies)
print(nes) # 2 NE solutions exist
# [('T', 'L'), ('B', 'R')]
```

In case of mixed strategy equilibrium, we need to solve a linear system of equations, For example, consider the following payoff table

```
#              player 2 
#              S1      S2         probability
# player 1 S1  a \ e   b \ f      p_1 
#          S2  c \ g   d \ h      p_2
# probability    q_1     q_2
```

The player1 takes strategy `S1`, `S2` with probability `p_1` and `p_2`, respectively.

The player2 takes strategy `S1`, `S2` with probability `q_1` and `q_2`, respectively.

Then we must have `p_1 + p_2 = 1` and `q_1 + q_2 = 1`.

At Nash equilibrium, player2 becomes indifferent of his strategy `S1` and `S2`, so we must have the expected payoffs equal:

`p_1*a + p_2*c = p_1*b + p_2*d => p_1(a-b) + p_2*(c-d) = 0`

Hence we have the following linear system of equations to solve for `(p_1, p_2)` at NE:

`1*p_1 +     1*p_2 = 1`

`(a-b)*p_1 + (c-d)*p_2 = 0`

In matrix form, in order to find `(p_1, p_2)` at NE, we need to `solve(A, b)`, where `A = [[1, 1], [a-b, c-d]]` and `b=[1,0]`. Similarly for `(q_1, q_2)`, we need to solve another linear system.

Generalizing, we can implement the mixed strategy NE as follows.

```
def get_mixed_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies):
    m, n = len(p1_strategies), len(p2_strategies)
    assert(m == n) # assuming player1 and player2 have same number of strategies, for simplicity
    A = np.zeros((m, m))
    b = [1] + [0]*(m-1)
    A[0] = [1]*m  # p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_m = 1
    for j in range(n-1):
        for i in range(m):
            s, s1, s2 = p1_strategies[i], p2_strategies[j], p2_strategies[j+1]
            A[j+1, i] = payoffs_df.loc[(payoffs_df['p1_strategy'] == s) & (payoffs_df['p2_strategy'] == s1), 'p2_payoff']
            A[j+1, i] -= payoffs_df.loc[(payoffs_df['p1_strategy'] == s) & (payoffs_df['p2_strategy'] == s2), 'p2_payoff']
    ps = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    A = np.zeros((n, n))
    b = [1] + [0]*(n-1)
    A[0] = [1]*n  # q_1 + q_2 + ... + q_n = 1
    for j in range(m-1):
        for i in range(n):
            s, s1, s2 = p2_strategies[i], p1_strategies[j], p1_strategies[j+1]
            A[j+1, i] = payoffs_df.loc[(payoffs_df['p2_strategy'] == s) & (payoffs_df['p1_strategy'] == s1), 'p1_payoff']
            A[j+1, i] -= payoffs_df.loc[(payoffs_df['p2_strategy'] == s) & (payoffs_df['p1_strategy'] == s2), 'p1_payoff']
    qs = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    return (ps, qs)
```

Now, let's test the following game for the existence of DS, pure NE and mixed NE:

```
p1_strategies = ['H', 'T']
p2_strategies = ['H', 'T']
payoffs_df = pd.DataFrame({'p1_strategy': ['H', 'H', 'T', 'T'],
                           'p2_strategy': ['H', 'T', 'H', 'T'],
                           'p1_payoff': [1, -1, -1, 1],
                           'p2_payoff': [-1, 1, 1, -1]})
print(payoffs_df)
#  p1_strategy p2_strategy  p1_payoff  p2_payoff
#0           H           H          1         -1
#1           H           T         -1          1
#2           T           H         -1          1
#3           T           T          1         -1
ds_p1 = get_dominating_strategy('p1', payoffs_df, p2_strategies)
ds_p2 = get_dominating_strategy('p2', payoffs_df, p1_strategies)
print(ds_p1, ds_p2)
# None None
nes = get_pure_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies)
print(nes)
# None
ps, qs = get_mixed_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies)
print(ps, qs)
# [0.5 0.5] [0.5 0.5]
```

Note that both DS and pure NE don't exist in above case where a mixed NE exists.

Let's try another game, where the same thing happens, although with different probabilities:

```
p1_strategies = ['F', 'B']
p2_strategies = ['F', 'B']
payoffs_df = pd.DataFrame({'p1_strategy': ['F', 'F', 'B', 'B'],
                           'p2_strategy': ['F', 'B', 'F', 'B'],
                           'p1_payoff': [90, 20, 30, 60],
                           'p2_payoff': [10, 80, 70, 40]})
print(payoffs_df)
#  p1_strategy p2_strategy  p1_payoff  p2_payoff
#0           F           F         90         10
#1           F           B         20         80
#2           B           F         30         70
#3           B           B         60         40
ds_p1 = get_dominating_strategy('p1', payoffs_df, p2_strategies)
ds_p2 = get_dominating_strategy('p2', payoffs_df, p1_strategies)
print(ds_p1, ds_p2)
# None None
nes = get_pure_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies)
print(nes)
# None
ps, qs = get_mixed_nash_equilibriums(payoffs_df, p1_strategies, p2_strategies)
print(ps, qs)
# [0.3 0.7] [0.4 0.6]
```